# Adding a number value to sales rep attribute of account entity by using plug ins in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have written a code in class library after that I did build the code and copied code to 
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\assembly`

I tried to simulate the work. It is not populating the value in the form.

Can anyone help me how can this be fixed?

```
public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
    DynamicEntity entity = null;

    if (context.InputParameters.Properties.Contains("Target") &&
        context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"] is DynamicEntity)
    {
        entity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];
        if (entity.Name != EntityName.account.ToString()) { return; }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // DynamicEntity followup = new DynamicEntity();
        CrmNumber gcs_numb = new CrmNumber();
        gcs_numb.Value = 10;
        //follow.Properties = new PropertyCollection();
        entity.Properties.Add(new CrmNumberProperty("gcs_numberofsalesreps", gcs_numb));
    }
    catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
                "An error occurred in the Account plug-in.", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things, I would kindly ask for some more info:

**How did you register the plugin?** Typically, you would want this registered synchronously on a pre-event i.e Create. Using the [Plugin Registration Tool](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmplugin)

Are you omitting a call to **ICrmService.Update**?

```
ICrmService service = context.CreateCrmService(true);
service.Update(entity);
```

**Have you created your custom fields, and published them correctly?**
*gcs_numberofsalesreps* must exist as a valid number field on the *account* entity.

Comment: Depending on the message and stage an explicit update is not necessary as you can alter the record which is processed directly.